# Listas em HTML5

Tags: html, css3, lista

Estou fazendo um site de videos e queria colocar uma pagina com varios videos um do lado do outro, eu tentei fazer criando div por div ficou certo na minha resolução mas para outras resoluções o conteudo passa da janela, era isso que eu queria arrumas, criar por exemplo uma lista que fosse até o fim da pagina (no eixo x) e pulasse uma linha automaticamente, tipo uma ul só que no eixo x e que quando chegasse no final da pagina ela pulasse uma linha com o resto dos videos.

Comment: Você poderia começar por estudar técnicas e ferramentas de design responsivo, como Medias Queries do CSS3 ou Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, mas por acaso você não sabe nenhum comando do html que ja faça isso?